# QT QML accessing root context properties in "ui.qml" files

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am building ".ui.qml" file using QTDesingStudio.
In the application, I am using a scaling ratio to scale the UI as per the screen size.

```
float scalef = (screenWidth / TARGET_SWIDTH);
QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("scalef", scalef);
```

I can access `scalef` variable in `.qml` files but not in the `.ui.qml` files while building the UI using the QT designer and because of that I don't see the Frame properly getting drawn in the designer. But yes at the runtime UI is drawn properly, as `.ui.qml` is getting embedded in `.qml` file.

Is there a way to define some dummy/place holder variable the same as `scalef` with some hardcoded values in QT designer so that I can see the UI Frame while designing.

Comment: If you temporarily scale your root qml component by scalef in the qml file will it solve your issue?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Hammin, yes it does solve but for few of the components I need to add scale inside the ui.qml file as to make the width of the components to scale. so when I add it I don't see the component getting drawn correctly inside the designer frame view.